# How to store a byte array as an image file on disk?

Tags: java, image, io, arrays

I have a byte array representation of a Image. How to save it on disk as an image file.

I have already done this

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("a.jpg");
out.write(byteArray);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

But when I open the image by double-clicking it, it doesn't show any image.

Comment: do you mean to write it out as a PNG or JPG or just so that you can read it back in at some point?

Comment: do you have the kind of array you can pass to image.setRGB?

Comment: Where did you get the byte[] from? You need to know what format it has (JPEG, GIF, PNG, BMP...)

Comment: I think this is related to his other question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138961/how-to-convert-an-img-in-html-to-byte-in-java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Other than failing to use a try/finally block (at least in the code you've shown) that should be fine. (You don't need to flush an output stream if you're closing it, by the way.)

As it's not working, that suggests `byteArray` doesn't *actually* contain a JPEG-encoded image. How have you created `byteArray` to start with? If it's a "raw" representation, you'll probably want to encode it, e.g. using the [javax.imageio](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) package.

Comment: Could you also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132657/java-swing-architecture-problem/2132670#2132670 ................. Actually all suggested me to use MVC architecture of swing.... but I don't want that answer.... I already know it... I want a suggestion or a sample example of swing that has its gui code divided into several files... so that i can figure out my own problem... i searched on google a lot but couldn't get any such example...

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [FileOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) class:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("image.jpg");
try {
    fos.write(someByteArray);
}
finally {
    fos.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ImageIO API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html).

The details can be a bit hairy, but first you'll probably want to create a BufferedImage using TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED type and some suitable IndexColorModel instance. Then put your byte array there. Hint: you can get the internal representation of BufferedImage with:

```
myDataBuffer = myBufferedImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
```

Which will likely return a data buffer of type DataBufferByte (check!), from which you get a byte array with

```
myByteArray = ((DataBufferByte) myDataBuffer).getData();
```

Then you can use System.arraycopy to copy your byte array onto that.