# How to convert an <img... in html to byte [] in Java

Tags: java, image, htmlunit

I have opened a webpage in HtmlUnit headless browser. Now that webpage contains a image html tag as follows:

```
<img src="..." />
```

So I want that image only. But the problem is that the same src URL of the image shows diff. image each time. Means, if we refresh the img src URL, then it shows diff. image each time.

So how to get the image that is displayed on the html page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the [HTMLPage](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html), you have to get the image through one of its method. You can then get an [HtmlImage](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlImage.html), which can be saved as a file. You'll just have to analyse this file later.

Comment: Oh... yes... There is a method "saveAs()" in HtmlImage class....

Can I convert that HtmlImage directly into byte[] or I have to first save it and then convert the saved file into byte[]?

Comment: could you please look at the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131049/problem-in-htmlunit-api-for-java-headless-browser

Comment: You can use `getWebResponse` and get the content as byte[]

Answer (score 0):

This is the function to store your image with fully qualified I

```
   protected String saveImage(String imageUrl) throws Exception {

   InputStream inputStream;
   OutputStream os;
   ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream;
   String destinationFile = "File path where you want ot store the image";
   URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
   inputStream = url.openStream();
   byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);
   int read;
   String barcode = null;
   while ((read = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
       os.write(read);
       byteArrayOutputStream.write(read);
       barcode = byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
   }
   inputStream.close();
   os.close();
   byteArrayOutputStream.close();



   return barcode;
```

}