# HtmlUnit Save Image Quality

Tags: htmlunit

I'm creating code to download some images from the web using HtmlUnit.
But when I save the image with HtmlUnit the quality of the image is very low compared with the original image.
I used this code to save the img url to a file.

```java
 try {
              HtmlImage imgX = (HtmlImage) 
              page.getByXPath("//img").get(0);
              Thread.sleep(3000);

              File imageFile = new File(dir +"/"+ name);
              imgX.saveAs(imageFile);
              System.out.println("Done!!!!");
 } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Are there other options to get the image with the best quality?

I tried using this:
[How to convert an <img... in html to byte [] in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138961/how-to-convert-an-img-in-html-to-byte-in-java)
But the image was not created.

Comment: Can you post your complete case, with actual image?

Answer (score 0):

Get the [WebResponse](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebResponse.html) from [HtmlImage](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlImage.html):

```
InputStream inputStream = imgX.getWebResponse(true).getContentAsStream();
```

And then work directly on InputStream:

```
File imageFile = new File(dir +"/"+ Name);
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
```

Comment: I am glad to help. Don't forget to mark answer as correct one. :)