# JAX-RS / REST / save image

Tags: web-services, file, jax-rs

For a web service, I receive more pictures that I have to register on the server.
I'm not sure which method to use, here's what I think declaring parameters as:

```java
@FormParam("photos") List<File> photos
```

Also, I do not know how to save a file received in this way. I see many example of creating a file from a path, but not from an existing file.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably do something similar to this :

```
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("image.jpg");
    try {
        fos.write(someByteArray);
    }
    finally {
        fos.close();
    }
```

Taken from here: [How to store a byte array as an image file on disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138913/how-to-store-a-byte-array-as-an-image-file-on-disk)

Comment: Thank you for your message. I found a solution, I convert my image in byte[], and in my web service, I receive a parameter with the format byte[]

Comment: finally, I use this solution [link]http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-resteasy/